Can I extract Airbnb pricing info into google spreadsheet using appscript?
I'm trying to create a custom function on appscript which would give me the price info of a particular Airbnb listing. Is that possible? I know I cant use Importxml function since its not static but I thought it would be possible to build a custom function via appscript. I keep getting the error message "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."
Here's what I have:
function myFunction() {

var BNB = "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/567207059536369934?source_impression_id=p3_1717642603_P3K-jlvEKresdSUq&check_in=2024-08-03&guests=1&adults=1&check_out=2024-09-03";
var x = UrlFetchApp.fetch(BNB);

//Logger.log(x);
var temp = Cheerio.load(x.getContentText());
//Logger.log(temp);
var monthrate = temp("_ati8ih");

Logger.log(monthrate);
}


Can I ask you about the details of your expected value?

Is your code based on cheerio for Google Apps Script? As a matter of interest, did you add the Cheerios library to your project?

@Tedinoz Yes, I've added the library to the project

@Tanaike Well, its supposed to be the monthly rate of the Airbnb, the main number above the reservation dates. However if I could get the details, accommodations, cleaning fee etc, I don't really mind, I can calculate the number I'm looking for. Hope that makes sense!

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from its supposed to be the monthly rate of the Airbnb, the main number above the reservation dates. However if I could get the details, accommodations, cleaning fee etc, I don't really mind, I can calculate the number I'm looking for., I cannot still understand your expected value. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

@Tanaike No worries! Thank you for taking a look at it, I really appreciate it :)
Are you able to open this link on your browser?
Link: https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/567207059536369934?source_impression_id=p3_1717642603_P3K-jlvEKresdSUq&check_in=2024-08-03&guests=1&adults=1&check_out=2024-09-03
So if you scroll a little, you'll see the box with all the pricing details for those specific dates. On the top part of the box, there's a number that's slashed and a new number next to it. I am looking for that number, the number next to the slashed number. Let me know if you have trouble!

Thank you for replying. I think that I understood your expected value. So, when I saw the HTML of your URL, I noticed that your expected value is retrieved from an API with Javascript. By this, unfortunately, your expected value cannot be retrieved by UrlFetchApp.fetch. Also, it seems that the request to the API cannot be run from Google Apps Script. From this situation, I guess that in the current stage, your expected value might not be able to be retrieved by Google Apps Script. I apologize for this situation.

Gotcha, thank you @Tanaike Any idea how I can retrieve the data? Maybe just have to write a program for it
